# Text-shadow on li element carrying over to sub menu (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a dropdown menu here http://watercookies.topfloorstudio.com/

I want the main menu items (Engage, Play, View, etc...) to have the text-shadow but not the dropdown menu items.. I've tried specific selectors which didn't work and I tried classes applied to only those elements and the sub li elements still had the text shadow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "text-shadow: none" to this line in your CSS.

```
ul#main-nav li ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    **text-shadow: none;**
}
```

Comment: No problem. I used to get stuck on this kind of thing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS:

```
ul#main-nav li { 
    float: left;
    font-family: "Oswald", "Impact", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #666666;
}
```

It is catching *all* of the `li`s.  Move the drop shadow to this selector:

```
ul#main-nav > li > a
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Found the solution above. Thanks!